# Accessing a webservice running as a virtual directory, with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have an MVC web application that is making a server-side call to a webservice, using System.Net.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync.

This is working fine, when the webservice is running as a root site in IIS. But when we configure it in IIS as a virtual directory, System.Net.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync is posting to the wrong URL.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
      var webServiceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebServiceUrl"];
      if (webServiceUrl == null)
           throw new Exception("WebServiceUrl not set in web.config");

      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webServiceUrl);
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
      new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

      HttpResponseMessage response = 
           await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Authentication", loginModel);

      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           ...
```

When I trace through this in the debugger, I see that webServiceUrl is set to a domain+virtual directory (i.e., http://mydomain.com/myvirtualdirectory).

And then when I get the response, it has a StatusCode 404, "Not Found". And here's the thing - the response object contains the RequestMessage, and the URL in the request does not include the virtual directory.

We had started with a BaseAddress of "http://mydomain.com/myvirtualdirectory" and a RequestUri of "api/Authentication", and what I see in the RequestMessage is "http://mydomain.com/api/Authentication". The virtual directory has been stripped out.

The question is, why?

Comment: Read the question, before you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems clear here: WebClient has no idea about virtual directories. From the perspective of the client, a virtual directory is just another folder. So instead of

```
await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Authentication", loginModel);
```

you should use:

```
await client.PostAsJsonAsync("myvirtualdirectory/api/Authentication", loginModel);
```

Comment: If I do not use BaseAddress, but instead pass a full URI into PostAsJsonAsync(), things work fine. What is clear is that HttpClient.BaseAddress is misnamed - it's used as a site domain name, rather than as the base address of a site.

Comment: It's not misnamed. From the client perspective `mysite.com` is a base address, while `mysite.com/myvirtualdirectory` is just a folder at `mysite.com`.

Comment: When I set HttpClient.BaseAddress to mysite.com/myvirtualdirectory, I am telling HttpClient that that is my base address. Or so I would suppose, from the naming and the documentations. Oddly enough, it only seems to treat it as a base address if it ends in a "/". Which makes no sense at all.

Comment: I don't think `WebClient` is sealed. You're welcome to change how it behaves.

Comment: I just had a similar issue. My baseAddress was something like: https://www.myservice.com/myvirtualdirectory. The trick for me was to simply add a trailing forward slash at the end, turning it to: https://www.myservice.com/myvirtualdirectory/  Problem solved. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: @hamiltonjose This answer was posted 7 years ago. WebClient is a very archaic way of connecting to an HTTP API. There's much better choices now: HttpClientFactory, Flurl, RestSharp. I suggest you investigate those. [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) in particular has a very nice syntax for building URL's.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you want the `BaseUri` to end with a slash.

Imagine, your browser is on `http://example.com/myvirtualdirectory` and there is a link to `api`.
Where will it go?

To `http://example.com/api`.

Imagine, there is a link to `api/Authentication`. 
Where does it point to? 
To `http://example.com/api/Authentication`.

So you see why it works out like that. *You* know that `myvirtualdirectory` is a directory but it doesn't look like it to the machine.

Comment: I don't want anything to depend on whether a path or URL in a web.config setting ends or does not end in a slash. It's a configuration error that is just screaming to happen. Still, if I add the slash, I get the behavior I want - the path in the Post is appended to the BaseAddress.

Comment: @JeffDege what can I tell you? This is how it is specified and it makes sense to me. Your input is not correct. Fix it. Or, define a URL prefix in your web.config. I don't get why you need BaseUri anyway. Just append strings. On app startup, add `assert(myBaseUri.StartsWith("/"))` and errors will be noticed immediately.

Comment: From the other comment I can tell that you have not understood how BaseAddress works. It works exactly the same as the browser does it. It does more than simple string concatenation.

Comment: It's clear that I don't understand how BaseAddress works.  That I don't indicates either a failure in the documentation for BaseAddress, or if its design.  In this case, I'd say both.  There is no documentation of BaseAddress that I've been able to find that discusses these issues. As for design, what is BaseAddress supposed to represent, other that the root URL of the website?  And that the behavior changes based on the presence or absence of a directory separator is a clear violation of the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: Still, complaining about MS's design or documentation problems is unproductive.  Thanks, all, for helping find a solution.

Comment: You are right with that. BaseAddress works the same way that combining URIs always does on the web. This is not .NET specific. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885373/how-to-combine-uris for another .NET specific case.