# HttpClient Modifies BaseAddress in Some Cases

Tags: c#, .net, uri, dotnet-httpclient

On a basic level, I should be able to set an absolute `BaseAddress` on `HttpClient` and then send Http requests with a relative `Uri`. The expectation is that the relative `Uri` would append on to the base address to make the Http call. It does this in most cases. This example works fine.

**Edit: see the bottom. This appears to be weird behavior in the way Uris are constructed.**

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://restcountries.eu/rest/", UriKind.Absolute) };
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("v2", UriKind.Relative));
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**Fiddler url:**

> GET http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2 HTTP/1.1

I have a local API. When I run the equivalent on my local API, the call truncates part of the base address ("Api").

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://localhost/JsonPerson/Api", UriKind.Absolute) };
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("GetApiPerson", UriKind.Relative));
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**Fiddler url:**

> GET http://localhost/JsonPerson/GetApiPerson HTTP/1.1

**Why does is it remove "/Api" ?**

This code hits the local API and works fine:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://localhost/JsonPerson/", UriKind.Absolute) };
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("Api/GetApiPerson", UriKind.Relative));
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**Fiddler url:**

> GET http://localhost/JsonPerson/Api/GetApiPerson HTTP/1.1

This is a bizarre problem and I can't figure out why I get these inconsistencies... Is it treating the uri differently for local and non local uris? What am I missing here?

This is .NET Core 3.1

Look at this code, and then have a look at the output. This is what `HttpClient` is doing behind the scenes.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var baseAddress = new Uri($"http://restcountries.eu/JsonPerson/Api", UriKind.Absolute);
            var resourceUri = new Uri($"GetApiPerson", UriKind.Relative);
            Console.WriteLine(new Uri(baseAddress, resourceUri));

            baseAddress = new Uri($"http://restcountries.eu/JsonPerson", UriKind.Absolute);
            resourceUri = new Uri($"Api/GetApiPerson", UriKind.Relative);
            Console.WriteLine(new Uri(baseAddress, resourceUri));

            baseAddress = new Uri($"http://restcountries.eu/rest/", UriKind.Absolute);
            resourceUri = new Uri($"v2", UriKind.Relative);
            Console.WriteLine(new Uri(baseAddress, resourceUri));
        }
    }
}
```

Output

> http://restcountries.eu/JsonPerson/GetApiPerson

> http://restcountries.eu/Api/GetApiPerson

> http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2

It turns out that this thing seems to have something to do with it...

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/f461f1986ca4027720656a0c77bede9963e20b7e/System/net/System/UriExt.cs#L742

Comment: This does look like a bug. I've tried following how `HttpRequestMessage.RequestUri` [is used](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpRequestMessage.cs,7f16a0aef607696b,references) and quickly given up :)  Maybe, worth reporting to .NET repro.

Comment: I'm looking through the code now, but it's so confusing

Comment: Nope! The problem is much more simple. It's with Url concatenation.

Comment: Just add a slash to terminate the Url part: `http://restcountries.eu/JsonPerson/Api/`, `http://restcountries.eu/JsonPerson/` etc.

Comment: IMO that's quite unintuitive that we need to add slash for `BaseAddress`. Is it documented anywhere? Please post you findings as an answer, pretty sure other people will run into this, me including :)

Answer (score 6):

Putting a slash on the end of the `BaseAddress` resolves the issue.

However, this kind of seems like a bug in `Uri` to me. I'm sure this trips up tonnes of people.

I created a library called [Urls](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Urls) which addresses this issue. Urls are immutable and you don't have to construct them with strings.

[RestClient.Net](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net) is a REST/HTTP client library that uses these urls. You can read more about the issue [here](https://christianfindlay.com/2021/05/26/restclient-net-5/).

Comment: But you definitely would agree that *totally different* case of `http://example.com/root/home.aspx` combined with `other.aspx` should result in `http://example.com/root/other.aspx`, wouldn't you?

Comment: My above comment turned out to be plagiarized version of Jon Skeet's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/885390/477420... let's consider this attribution to comment (and close as duplicate).